# New record using Entity Framework DataLayer Repository Add() Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner to Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC and learning it from online tutorials, I made a class library datalayer (`Student.DataLayer`) first, in which I have a `Repository.cs`, where I have all the functions like

```
protected readonly ObjectContext _connection;
public Repository(IConnectionHelper connection)
{
    _connection = connection.Connection;
}

public virtual ObjectSet<T> ObjectSet
{
    get
    {
        return

        _connection.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
}

public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return ObjectSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        ObjectSet.AddObject(entity);
        Save();
        return entity;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _connection.SaveChanges();

     }
```

in `IRepository.cs` I have

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T Add(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Now I have add the reference of `Student.Datalayer` in the main ASP.NET MVC3 project `Student`, so I can access all the functions of datalayer now.

I have a table in database with the name `Student`, and it only have `student_id` and `student_first_name` and `student_last_name` columns

So far I have managed to update records in model which are already added

```
    public bool update_name(int id, string newfirstname, string newlastname)
    {
        var stud = _stu.Get(p => p.student_id == id);
         stud.student_first_name = newfirstname;
         stud.student_last_name = newlastname;
        _stu.Save();
        return true;
    }
```

but how to add a new record in the table using `_stu.Add()`, I can't figure this out. I am trying like below.

```
    public bool add_Student(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
       _stu.Add( //what to do here
       return true;
    }
```

I really want to know this way, because using datalayer like this approach, it's very clean. So please help me

Comment: You should just call Add() on your repository and pass in a student object. That'll add the given student to your DbSet and then call Save() on your DbContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add_Student()` function you have has no dependencies, ie., no parameters. I assume you would need some parameters like the students first and last name, maybe email address, etc.

And then use that to create a new student:

```
public bool add_Student(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    //Requires code to get the new ID, 
    //unless your ObjectSet classes creates the ID automatically.
    int newStudentID = 1; 

    var s = new StudentObject() 
    {
        id = newStudentID, //may not need to be here
        FirstName = firstname,
        LastName = lastname
    };

    _stu.Add(s)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should I have added two parameters firstname and lastname to the add_student function, I tried it `var s = new Datalayer.Student
    {
        FirstName = firstname,
        LastName = lastname
    };

    _stu.Add(s)` but its giving me error that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. and NULLReference exception is unhandled by user code"

Comment: I'm not for sure, but syntactically you might have to have the () in there: `new Datalayer.Student() {`

Comment: Yeah I have done that, but still the same error that "NULLReference exception is unhandled by user code"

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Is `_stu` null? In the `Add` routine, is `ObjectSet` null?

Comment: Based on the code you have presented, `_connection` is the only other object from which you are calling a method/property that could possibly be null which could throw this error.

Comment: `public Repository(IConnectionHelper connection)
        {
            _connection = connection.Connection;
        }

        public virtual ObjectSet<T> ObjectSet
        {
            get
            {
                return

                _connection.CreateObjectSet<T>();
            }
        }`

Comment: @ArbazAbid please update your question with the code rather than putting it into the comments.

Comment: just updated the question, and added connectionhelper and objectset function to the repository.cs

Comment: Bottom line is that this null reference error occurs when you try to call a method or property on a variable with a null value. So it could be `_stu` that is null. You can try `if (_stu != null) _stu.Add(s);` and if no error occurs then you know there is a problem with `_stu`.

Comment: thanks buddy, that worked, I found that _stu was referenced with another table in controller. changed that to student and working like a charm. accepted your answer. Thanks for your time.